# How to fix this git merge issue QUICKLY when differences are not important?

Tags: git

I got an unexpected problems with git and I have no idea why or how to fix it.

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 3 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

What command to should I use to see how branches have diverged?

But more importantly, when I do `git pull` I get nasty merge conflicts in uglified js files & similar not important files.

I have reset the merge using

```
git reset --merge
```

How to resolve that conflict quickly?

Comment: Perhaps you should spend time reading so that you *do* know what to do when the problem occurs? Apparently it recurs regularly, albeit infrequently.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the merge, then resolve the conflicts by checking out either your or their copy of the conflicted files. Then add those files into the commit.

```
git pull origin master
```

Then either;

```
git checkout --ours FILE/PATH
```

Or;

```
git checkout --theirs FILE/PATH
```

Depending on whether you want to use your copy or their copy. My guess is it doesn't matter - as you can now run your build scripts to create correct copies of these files.

Once you've generated your new files, you'll have to add them to the commit;

```
git add FILE/PATH
```

Then commit;

```
git commit -m "Merging remote changes"
```

Then finally push the changes to your remote;

```
git push origin master
```

**Edit**

In my opinion, if it's worth much, using a default level strategy for conflicts isn't a good idea. Yes - it'll handle your `dist` or `build` files - but you could also miss **important** conflicts in your src files.

It is possible to alter the configuration for your local Repository and set specific merge strategies for specific files.

**However I'm unsure if this works with `git pull`.**

To do this, you'll need to create a file in `.git/info/attributes` with the contents;

```
FILE/PATH merge=ours
```

Then you'll need to update your git config;

```
git config merge.ours.driver true
```

Now, you shouldn't see these files appear as conflicts.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it directly in git pull? `git pull --strategy=ours` or something?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš I've edited my answer - personally I'd still do the manual `checkout`'s though - seeing as you said you only come across this issue infrequently.